# Raspberry pi python mysql code stops saving data after a while

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi, mysql-python, raspbian

I'm new at this blog although I've used several tips on publications done here.
I have a code that reads the GPS position, and other data from another device. After this, I do some calculations and store the data in a database and a text file. My problem is that after a while it stops storing the data, but the code keeps running. Any idea why? 
My code is a little extensive, but basically it creates two serial variables so I can read two different devices.
Then in a infinite loop I do the following:

1. open database
2. manipulate and analyze data
3. store data in txt file
4. store data in mysql
5. close connection

All of this with a try catch so i can save any exception in another text file.
The code I use to store ina  text file is:

```
with open("datos.txt", "a") as mydata:
        mydata.write("(" + str(hora)+","+str(latitud)+","+str(longitud)+",#"+str(color)+","+str(latitudReal)+","+str(longitudReal)+","+str(libre)+","+espectro+")" + ", " + cc1 + "\n")
        mydata.flush()
        mydata.close()
```

The code to store in the mysql database is:

```
try:
        sql2 = "INSERT INTO pichincha101(hora, latitud, longitud, color, latitudReal, longitudReal, porcentaje, espectro) VALUES ('"+str(hora)+"','"+str(latitud)+"','"+str(longitud)+"','#"+str(color)+"','"+str(latitudReal)+"','"+str(longitudReal)+"','"+str(libre)+"','"+espectro+"')"
        cur.execute(sql2)
        db.commit()
except Exception  as e:
        print "error INSERT mysql"
        print e
```

I'm also deleting some arrays and cleaning up the ram before doing it again with this code:

```
del res1
del res2
del ampp
del amp1
os.system("echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches")
```

It's the same problem even if I dont include the last code section I just published.

In advanced, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a timeout in your mysql (SQL_TIMEOUT) or your server settings? For example, when I work in Apache, I have to adjust the max_execution_time variable. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was empting the buffers from my serial devices. Hope it helps someone else.